# Doubt in computation of inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

I need to show that if $$(Ta|a)=(T^*(a) |a) $$

Then $$T=T^*$$

Some hints would be helpful instead of a complete answer.

Comment: Hint: use the polarization identity to show the relation for any $a,b$ instead of just the quadratic form with $a,a$. See this for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3035810/399263

Comment: Once you showed by polarization that this implies $(T(a)|b)=(T^*(a)|b)$ for all $a,b$ this implies $((T-T^*)(a),b)=0$ for all $a,b$ thus for $b=(T-T^*)(a)$ you get $((T-T^*)(a)|(T-T^ *)(a))=0$ for all $a$, thus $(T-T^*)(a)=0$ for all $a$, thus $T=T^*$