# Polarization identity sesquilinear form

Tags: multilinear-algebra, sesquilinear-forms

I don't understand why [sometimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3035810/603403) the polarization identity for sesquilinear form $m$ is written as
$$
m(x,y)= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^{n}Q(x+i^{n}y)
$$
with $Q(x)=m(x,x)$ and [other times](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/polarization+identity) as
$$
m(x,y)= \frac{1}{4}(Q(x+y)-Q(x-y)-iQ(x+iy)+iQ(x-iy))
$$
which are different.

Comment: Just to be clear, is $Q$ a map from a complex vector space to $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $Q(\lambda v) = |\lambda|^2Q(v)$?

Comment: Yes, it follows from the fact that $m$ is sesquilinear

Comment: If $Q$ were defined in terms of $m$, then that would be true, but you are asking about the opposite situation (defining $m$ in terms of $Q$), hence why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m(x, y) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^3i^nQ(x+i^ny)$. Then $m$ satisfies $m(ix, y) = im(x, y)$ and $m(x, iy) = -im(x, y)$. That is, $m$ is complex linear in the first argument and conjugate linear in the second argument.

Let $m'(x, y) = \frac{1}{4}[Q(x+y) - Q(x-y) -iQ(x+iy) + iQ(x-iy)]$. Then $m'$ satisfies $m'(ix, y) = -im'(x, y)$ and $m'(x, iy) = im'(x, y)$. That is, $m'$ is conjugate linear in the first argument and complex linear in the argument.

So the correct formula depends on your definition of sesquilinearity (namely, which argument is complex linear and which argument is conjugate linear). Note that the two are related by $m'(x, y) = \overline{m(x, y)}$.